# Thermistor types

Tags: thermistor

What is the difference between the different types of thermistor? I'm talking about the differences between Type J and Type 2 for instance, and not talking about NTC vs PTC.

Edit:
I'm not looking for a difference between two specific parts or types, but rather the difference between all the types in general. I chose Type J and Type 2 solely because they were the first two to come across my desk.

edit2:
[image: Example Type J Thermistor]

Comment: Please provide links to the devices.

Comment: I'm wanting a more general answer, and less so about specific parts. I see a lot of different "types" of thermistor in my day to day work and the type is currently meaningless to me, and Google searches haven't been very helpful

Comment: I think you'd be better off doing as I ask.

Comment: Type J: https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwiMzurkovzTAhXHjlQKHQwHC5IQFgheMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thermometricscorp.com%2FPDFs%2FThermocouple-Charts%2FType-J-Thermocouple-Chart-C.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEHznnNjsmHSEtKFG3dH_aohk70fQ&sig2=ecEqQdKKvJx9CCHpOHBX_A
Type 2: https://www.kele.com/product/temperature-sensors-and-transmitters/duct/greystone-energy-systems/te200b24b2

Comment: I'm trying to help so don't throw google search engines at me. Are you sure you don't mean a type J thermocouple (note the spelling difference).

Comment: Thermistor for sure. Temperature dependent resistor. I've been designing in Type J Thermistors into the products I design for years now.

Comment: Also my apology about the Google search link, I grabbed the wrong one, I have updated my post to have the link I was originally trying to include

Comment: So how come the first link now takes you to thermo **couples**?

Comment: I was trying to quickly find something on Google and grabbed the first link I could find. I'll try to find the spec sheet for my Thermistor and post a link to that instead.

Comment: Afaik "Type J"  is a thermocouple not a thermistor.

Comment: I edited my original question to add a screen shot of the thermistor we use from US sensor

Comment: Speak to that supplier about curve J - it doesn't  sound like anything generic to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designation is specific to that vendor most likely. Their [curve J](http://www.ussensor.com/thermistor-part-number-103jf1k-resistance-vs-temperature-table) is an NTC with B25/B85 = ~3977K which is a really common characteristic.

Some other manufacturer may make a thermistor with a really similar characteristic but will have some other designation (or none at all) for the curve.